firebase signInWithCredential return phone number with null (Flutter)
firebase signInWithCredential return phone number with null when i sign in with social media like google or facebook
this is the sample of firebase response:

{"additionalUserInfo": {"isNewUser": true,"user": {"displayName":"i set it private","email":
"i set it private","phoneNumber":null,"photoURL":"i set it private"}}

i try this function with google and same for facebook and apple :
void googleSingIn() async {
  emit(GoogleAuthLoadingState());
  if (await checkConnectivity() == AppConstants.connectivityWifi ||
      await checkConnectivity() == AppConstants.connectivitymobile) {
    try {
      // Trigger the authentication flow
      final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();

      if (googleSignInAccount == null) {
        return;
      }

      // Obtain the auth details from the request
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      // Create a new credential
      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);

      // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
      final userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      final googleUser = userCredential.user;
      final additionalUserInfo = userCredential.additionalUserInfo;
      dev.log("$userCredential");

      if (additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser == false) {
        login(
          email: googleUser!.email!,
          password: googleUser.uid,
          method: AppConstants.googleMethod,
        );
      } else {
        RouteGenerator.registerCubit.register(
          google: googleUser!.email,
          googlePassword: googleUser.uid,
          firstName: additionalUserInfo.profile?["given_name"],
          lastName: additionalUserInfo.profile?["family_name"],
          image: googleUser.photoURL,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(GoogleAuthErrorState(error: e.toString()));
    }
  } else {
    emit(LogInConnectivity(
        connectivityMessage: StringsManager.connectionError));
  }
}


On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Unless you're signing in with a phone number, the phone number field is unlikely to be populated.
Social sign-in providers (for privacy reasons) don't auto-expose a user's phone number by default, so if you want to get this - you will have to explicit ask for it (by adding the relevant scope). For an example of this, see how i can retrieve gender and phone number and birthdate from signInWithGoogle flutter

As far as I know, firebase social media sign-in are different than phone number sign in. This is phone sign documentation for web. I didn't test this myself but i think phone sign in is a different provider and if only user signs in with phone, then you can see phone provider and phone number in the user info.

when i sgin in with social media like google the firebase return response, this resopnse has data like email and name and phone number etc... , so i need this data to send it to my backend , the problem here in phone number always returned null

@AhmedHussein you won't get phone number when user signup with fb/google. imagine some app getting your personal mobile number when you signup using facebook.

so why they provided a phone number property in user response

According to the documentation for the phoneNumber property:

This is null if the user has no phone credential linked to the account.

So you can expect this to be null unless the user signed in with phone number authentication.
